# Преобразование в список категорий

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `RecyclerView`, в который я добавляю категории следующим образом:

```
private void initializeData() {
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("test", "sada", R.drawable.background_material_red));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "2dad", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "35 years old", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "sada", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "2dad", R.drawable.profile));
    persons.add(new Person("test", "35 years old", R.drawable.profile));
}
```

Но сейчас хочу преобразить это всё в простой список категорий (для будущих задач), как это возможно сделать?

Comment: А чем `простой список категорий` отличается от существующего?

Comment: @post_zeew дело в том, что в будущем мне придётся в моём классе контроллере создать метод, который из списка listCategory вернет элемент с выбранной позицией,чтоб потом в фрагменте из полученного Category забирать список listMarker и циклом проходится по этому списку чтобы создаеть маркеры с LatLng каждого MarkerData

Comment: Это все замечательно, но ответа на свой вопрос я так и не получил.

Comment: @post_zeew тем что я не очень представляю как потом проделывать операции описанные выше.

Comment: Из Вашего ответа я по-прежнему не понял, чем `простой список категорий` отличается от уже существующего. Для ответа на Ваш вопрос (как минимум) нужно знать, что представляют собой эти Ваши списки категорий. Вот, допустим, у меня есть `ArrayList<String>` – отсюда сразу понятно, что у меня есть список строк. Попробуйте по аналогии (а если коллекция типизирована Вашим собственным типом – укажите что представляет собой этот тип).